# How does one log a QSO via a cross-band repeater?

Tags: satellites, logging, qsl-card, crossband-repeat

When working through a cross band repeater, either the two sides are using different bands or both sides are using two bands at once. At the same time, most if not all logging software (as well as most QSL card layouts) seem to assume that only one band is in use for any given QSO. Despite this, such QSOs must be logged (and QSL cards sent) all the time by satellite enthusiasts and users of terrestrial cross band repeaters.

So, **what is the "right" or customary way to log a crossband contact?** What does one write in the band field? Does anything need to be written in other fields? Should "cis" contacts (where both parties transmit on, say, VHF and listen on UHF) be logged differently from "trans" contacts (where one party uses only VHF and the other only UHF)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cross-band satellite contacts, the uplink and downlink frequencies, or at least the nominal frequencies of the bands used, should be logged.  Typically the frequencies are both stuffed into a "MHz" field, with an up arrow symbol next to the uplink frequency and a down arrow symbol next to the downlink frequency.  The name of the satellite should go on the QSL card somewhere, either in its own field or stuffed in the "Mode" field if a generic QSL card is being used.  (The "Mode" field should also show the mode, of course.)  A web search for "satellite QSL card" will show many examples.

A QSL card for a terrestrial cross-band contact should list the transmit and receive frequencies separately, showing which was which.

Most terrestrial repeaters don't operate cross-band, and the vast majority of repeater contacts aren't followed up by a QSL card.  Any QSL card for a repeater contact should explicitly make it clear that the QSO was over a repeater, since repeater contacts are not allowed in many contests.  I'd suggest stuffing "FM repeater K1ABC" into the "Mode" field, where "K1ABC" should be replaced by the call sign of the repeater used.

Comment: Both stations transmitting on VHF and listening on UHF (or the other way around) is exactly how satellite contacts work :)

Comment: Right you are @hobbs-KC2G, I was thinking about simplex ;)  I removed that paragraph.